# Get address by location

Tags: xaml, location, bing-maps

I'm using Bing Maps on Windows store app (XAML).
I have the longitude and the latitude and I want to get the address (if it exists) of the location.
How can I do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do what is called reverse geocoding. Take a look at the SearchManager class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn306041.aspx This will let you reverse geocode your coordinates and get the address.

Alternatively you can also use the Bing Maps REST services: 
This would be more work than using the search manager, but wouldn't require loading an interactive map first.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870778.aspx

Since it sounds like you are new to using Bing Maps in Windows Store apps I'd recommend downloading a free copy of my eBook on creating location intelligent Windows Store apps. It shows how to do this an a lot more. You can get a copy of it here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/my-book/